# Android (Kotlin) Two-Way Databinding with non-string primitive type

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-binding

I'm trying to do 2-way databinding in Android (Emulating a Pixel 3a running API level 29, with a min API target of 21). I want to use the `@={}` syntax on an EditText's `android:text` property.

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#converters) seems to say we can use a static converter class to convert to/from primitive (or presumably complex) data types, using an annotation to describe which methods reverse which others. I'm currently working with ints, but will also be working with doubles at least.

The conversion method from an Int to a string works fine. It's called when my fragment's layout is being inflated (though oddly, it's called twice immediately), however the conversion from a string back to an int is never hit with the debugger.

DatabindingConverters.kt

```kotlin
package com.razelon.svcman.database

import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.databinding.InverseMethod

object DatabindingConverters {

    @JvmStatic
    @InverseMethod("intToString")
    fun stringToInt(v: EditText, old: Int, new: String): Int {
        return new.toInt()
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun intToString(v: EditText, old: Int, new: Int): String {
        return new.toString()
    }
}
```

Excerpts from fragment_new_order.xml:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.razelon.svcman.orders.FragmentNewOrderViewModel" />

        <import type="com.razelon.svcman.database.DatabindingConverters" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/order_scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="48dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtWorkOrder"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:ems="6"
                android:hint="@string/hint_work_order"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"

                // The line in question, for XML
                android:text="@={DatabindingConverters.intToString(edtWorkOrder, viewModel.orderNo, viewModel.orderNo)}"


                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/edtAcct"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edtAcct" />


           // Other views

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

FragmentNewOrderViewModel.kt

```kotlin
package com.razelon.svcman.orders

import android.app.Application
import androidx.databinding.Bindable
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.razelon.svcman.database.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlin.math.max

const val MAX_WORK_CODES = 5

class FragmentNewOrderViewModel(
    val database: SvcDao,
    app: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val job = Job()

    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

    private val _listWorkCodes = MutableLiveData<List<WorkCode>>(listOf())

    private val _listParts = MutableLiveData<List<SvcPart>>(listOf())

    private val _eventResetOrder = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)

    val serviceMen = database.getAllServiceMen()

    val listWorkCodes: LiveData<List<WorkCode>>
        get() = _listWorkCodes

    val listSvcParts: LiveData<List<SvcPart>>
        get() = _listParts

    val eventResetOrder: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _eventResetOrder

    val orderNo = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)



    fun addWorkCode(): Boolean {
        if(_listWorkCodes.value!!.size >= MAX_WORK_CODES) {
            return false
        }
        _listWorkCodes.value = List<WorkCode>(_listWorkCodes.value!!.size + 1) {
            if (it < (_listWorkCodes.value!!.size)) {
                _listWorkCodes.value?.get(it)!!
            } else {
                WorkCode(0)
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    fun updateWorkCode(code: WorkCode) {

    }

    fun deleteWorkCode(pos: Int) {
        _listWorkCodes.value = List<WorkCode>(max(_listWorkCodes.value!!.size - 1, 0)) {
            if(it >= pos) _listWorkCodes.value!![it + 1] else _listWorkCodes.value!![it]
        }
    }

    fun addNewPart() {
        _listParts.value = List<SvcPart>(_listParts.value!!.size + 1) {
            if(it < _listParts.value!!.size) {
                _listParts.value!![it]
            } else {
                SvcPart("", 0.0, 1)
            }
        }
    }

    fun deletePart(pos: Int) {
        _listParts.value = List<SvcPart>(max(_listParts.value!!.size - 1, 0)) {
            if(it >= pos) _listParts.value!![it + 1] else _listParts.value!![it]
        }
    }


    fun resetOrder() {
        _eventResetOrder.value = true
        _listParts.value = listOf()
        _listWorkCodes.value = listOf()
    }

    fun onOrderReset() {
        _eventResetOrder.value = false
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss for why it isn't calling the inverse converter marked by the `@InverseMethod("intToString")` annotation. I've used the `object` keyword for the class declaration, marked the methods with the needed annotations, imported the type into my layout databind, and have the parameters in the methods matched up as documented. I am brand new to Kotlin and Android development, so I'm sure it could be something I'm overlooking easily, but any insight would be appreciated as to what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and it's entirely my fault. It's not shown in the post, but in my fragment, I never actually assigned the variable from the layout to my binding, so there was nothing for it to send the value back to.

Setting this fixed it for me, because I forgot it before:

FragmentNewOrder.kt

```kotlin
        val app = this.activity!!.application
        val ds = SvcDatabase.getInstance(app).DAO
        val factory = FragmentNewOrderViewModelFactory(ds, app)
        val viewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(FragmentNewOrderViewModel::class.java)

        // Very important, don't forget to bind your data 
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
```